# Convergence of the series $\sum\limits_{n = 4}^\infty {\frac{{n + 1}}{{(n + 5)(n + 4)(n - 3)}}}$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, divergent-series

To analyze the convergence of the 
$$\sum\limits_{n = 4}^\infty  {\frac{{n + 1}}{{(n + 5)(n + 4)(n - 3)}}}$$
series I used the criterion of integral $$\displaystyle\int_4^\infty  {\frac{{x + 1}}{{(x + 5)(x + 4)(x - 3)}}dx},$$ but calculate this improper integral is a very laborious task.

Is there a shorter way? What criteria of convergence would be most effective or simple?

Comment: Surely the series begins at $n\ge 4$ since the denominator is zero for $n=3$.

Comment: It does, and don't call me Shirley.

Comment: Indeed, the series starts at $n=4$. Thank you, and I corrected above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assume that the series begins at $n=4$.  Then, we have

$$n+5\ge n$$

$$n+4\ge n$$

$$n-3\ge \frac14 n$$

$$n+1\le 2n$$

Therefore, have

$$\frac{n+1}{(n+5)(n+4)(n-3)}\le \frac{2n}{\frac14 n^3}=8\frac1{n^2}$$

Finally, using the result $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{n^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$ reveals

$$\sum_{n=4}^{\infty}\frac{n+1}{(n+5)(n+4)(n-3)}\le 8\sum_{n=4}^{\infty}\frac1{n^2}=4\left(\frac{\pi^2}{3}-3\right)$$

and the series converges by the comparison test.

Comment: excellent!! thnaks

Comment: You're welcome!  My pleasure.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**, ignore the constants and this is the series:

$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n}{n^3}=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2}$$

which is convergent.

More formally, use the limit comparison test with $\frac{1}{n^2}$.

Answer (score 4):

$$\dfrac{n+1}{(n+5)(n+4)(n-3)} = -\dfrac12\cdot\dfrac1{n+5} + \dfrac37\cdot\dfrac1{n+4} + \dfrac1{14} \cdot\dfrac1{n-3}$$
Hence,
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=4}^{m} \dfrac{n+1}{(n+5)(n+4)(n-3)} & = - \dfrac12 \cdot \sum_{n=4}^{m} \dfrac1{n+5} + \dfrac37 \cdot \sum_{n=4}^{m} \dfrac1{n+4} + \dfrac1{14} \cdot \sum_{n=4}^{m} \dfrac1{n-3}\\
& = - \dfrac12 \sum_{n=9}^{m+5} \dfrac1n + \dfrac37 \sum_{n=8}^{m+4} \dfrac1n + \dfrac1{14} \sum_{n=1}^{m-3}\dfrac1n\\
& = - \dfrac12 \sum_{n=9}^{m+5} \dfrac1n + \dfrac37 \sum_{n=9}^{m+4} \dfrac1n + \dfrac1{14} \sum_{n=9}^{m-3}\dfrac1n + \dfrac37 \sum_{n=8}^{8} \dfrac1n + \dfrac1{14} \sum_{n=1}^{8}\dfrac1n\\
& = \dfrac{971}{3920} + \dfrac37 \sum_{m-2}^{m+4} \dfrac1n - \dfrac12 \sum_{m-2}^{m+5}\dfrac1n
\end{align}
Taking $m \to \infty$, we have $$\lim_{m \to \infty}\left(\dfrac37 \sum_{m-2}^{m+4} \dfrac1n - \dfrac12 \sum_{m-2}^{m+5}\dfrac1n \right) = 0$$
Hence,
$$\sum_{n=4}^{\infty} \dfrac{n+1}{(n+5)(n+4)(n-3)} = \dfrac{971}{3920}$$

Comment: Great!, many thanks.

Comment: @imj The manipulation are right; $\dfrac1{14}\sum_{n=9}^{m-3} \dfrac1n$ cancels with $\dfrac37 \sum_{n=9}^{m-3} - \dfrac12 \sum_{n=9}^{m-3}\dfrac1n$. And similarly the limit is clearly zero, since it is a sum of $15$ terms each of them going to zero.

Comment: my bad, I didn't see that you changed the beginnings of the sums.

Answer (score 0):

In the same spirit as Leg's answer, starting with the partial fraction decomposition $$\dfrac{n+1}{(n+5)(n+4)(n-3)} = -\dfrac12\cdot\dfrac1{n+5} + \dfrac37\cdot\dfrac1{n+4} + \dfrac1{14} \cdot\dfrac1{n-3}$$ and using harmonic numbers definition $$\sum_{n=p}^m \dfrac1{n+5}=H_{m+5}-H_{p+4}$$ $$\sum_{n=p}^m \dfrac1{n+4}=H_{m+4}-H_{p+3}$$ $$\sum_{n=p}^m \dfrac1{n-3}=H_{m-3}-H_{p-4}$$ which make $$A_p=\sum_{n=p}^m \dfrac{n+1}{(n+5)(n+4)(n-3)} =\frac{1}{14} \left(H_{m-3}+6 H_{m+4}-7 H_{m+5}-H_{p-4}+H_{p+3}+\frac{7}{p+4}\right)$$ When $m\to \infty$, $H_{m-3}+6 H_{m+4}-7 H_{m+5}\to 0$ and then, at the limit, $$A_p=\frac{1}{14}
   \left(\frac{1}{p-3}+\frac{1}{p-2}+\frac{1}{p-1}+\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{p+1}+\frac{1}{p+2}+\frac{1}
   {p+3}+\frac{7}{p+4}\right)$$ which gives $$A_4=\frac{971}{3920}$$ $$A_5=\frac{6289}{35280}$$ $$A_6=\frac{5113}{35280}$$ as so forth.